# Jquery mimic form post (json to Multipart-form)

Tags: jquery

I have want to do something like this to mimic a form post:

```
    $.ajax({
    url:url,
        type: "PUT",
    async:true,
    cache:false,
    data:
    {'end':end,'duration':duration}
    }
```

However, the data param only take data as a string, and the serialize() function only works if there is already a form.

Is there any way to parse the json array into a data string?  (Multipart form)

Comment: Hi, you can take a look at the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the fast response. Don't I need to put it as part of the request entity in the form format with separators and all? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think it only takes a string?  Do you want to mimic an actual PUT that PUTs two variables, `end` and `duration`, or do you want to PUT a JSON string?

> data    Object, String
>   Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a
>   query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for
>   GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic
>   processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array,
>   jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of
>   the traditional setting (described below).

Here is a jsfiddle (using POST) that shows that it will work:
http://jsfiddle.net/Hqgbj/

And a screenshot of firebug:
http://cl.ly/253g1f3g032t1a381l0u

Comment: Thanks. I want to put it as multipart form data.

Comment: Thank you. It was actually a server error that my server code did not look for $_POST when PUT command is received.

Comment: In PHP, you can't read data for PUT out of `$_POST`.  You need to read php://input.  Here is an example of what you can do: `parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$post_vars);` to dump the PUT data into an array called `$post_vars`.